# Redirection is working in opera but not in fennec and other mobile browsers?

Tags: php

I have a mobile website and I am redirecting mobile users from main website to mobile website. But I have also given option on my mobile website that if some mobile user want to visit the main website he can. To solve the problem I wrote this code on my main website

```
if (is_mobile()== true) //if user is browsing from mobile
{

    $main_website_url= 'http://localhost/www/redsignal/';   // main website URL

    $mobilesite_url = 'http://localhost/www/redsignal-mobile/';  //mobile website URL

    $mobilesite_url_length = strlen($mobilesite_url);

    $referring_path_url = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 0 , $mobilesite_url_length);

    if ($referring_path_url == $mobilesite_url) //This if condition checks that if the mobile user is coming from my mobile website or not
    {
        header("Location:".$main_website_url);  // if he is coming from mobile he will be redirected to main website                
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location:".$mobilesite_url); // if not than he will be redirected to mobile website     
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried this  if (is_mobile()== true) { .. } else {"echo 'not mobile';"} ? Maybe your is_mobile does not work correctly.

Comment: Try adding a space between `Location:` and the URL - so it becomes `header("Location: ".$main_website_url);`. Also try explicitly setting a response code: `header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');`

Comment: well I have checked it... it is a simple function which matches the USER HTTP AGENT with mobile browsers return true in match case and false in other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use another variable in order to distinguish whether you want to force show original site when click on visit original site in mobile site. For this u can pass GET variable for e.g.

http://localhost/www/redsignal/?force_show_original=1

Then in your code you change this

```
if (is_mobile()== true)
```

to

```
if (is_mobile()== true || $GET["force_show_original"] == true)
```

let me know whether it worked

**UPDATE**

Use following code to redirect site

```
if (is_mobile()== true || $GET["force_show_original"] == false) {
       //redirect to mobile site
}
else if(is_mobile()== true || $GET["force_show_original"] == true) {
       // redirect to original site
}
else {
       // redirect to original site
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if header not work than you can use javascript for redirection like

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location.href='$main_website_url'</script> ";
```

Comment: Relying on javascript for functionality you actually need is never a good idea.